# Manually trigger callback assigned to reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, callback, recaptcha

When a callback function is defined:

`src=https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit`

Is there any way to manually trigger it through the grecaptcha object?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you have to call it, just do:

```
 onloadCallback();
```

That won't generate a captcha token, but the captcha would otherwise be senseless if it could be bypassed in that way.

Comment: What about calling the api function that calls the callback, does the parent page have access to those functions?

Comment: @moonstone why?!

Comment: I need a solution that works for any callback function name, because I won't know what the function name is.